# C++ passing a const pointer by const reference

Tags: c++, constants

Hmm a strange one in VC2012 I can't seem to work out the syntax for passing a const pointer by const reference into a function of a templated class whose template argument is a non const pointer ie:

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo
{
    void Add( const T& Bar ) { printf(Bar); }
};

void main()
{
Foo<char*> foo;
const char* name = "FooBar"; 
foo.Add(name);                 // Causes error
}
```

So I've simplified my problem here but basically I want the argument to 'Add' to have a const T ie const char*.  I've tried:

```
void Add( const (const T)& Bar ); 

typedef const T ConstT;
void Add( const (ConstT)& Bar );  

void Add( const typename std::add_const<T>::type& Bar );
```

None of which work.  The exact error I'm getting is:

```
error C2664: 'Foo<T>::Add' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char *' to 'char *const &'
          with
          [
              T=char *
          ]
          Conversion loses qualifiers
```

which I can see is correct but how do I solve it without const casting 'name' to be non const.

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your issue here as that as soon as you have a pointer type mapped to a template type, you can no longer add const-ness to the pointed-to type, only to the pointer itself. What it looks like you're trying to do is automatically add constness to the parameter of your function (so if T is `char*` the function should accept `const char* const&` rather than `char* const&` as you've written). The only way to do that is with another template to add constness to the pointee for pointer types, as follows. I took the liberty of including missing headers and correcting the signature of `main`:

```
#include <cstdio>

template<typename T>
struct add_const_to_pointee
{
    typedef T type;
};

template <typename T>
struct add_const_to_pointee<T*>
{
    typedef const T* type;
};

template<typename T>
struct Foo
{
    void Add( typename add_const_to_pointee<T>::type const & Bar ) { printf(Bar); }
};

int main()
{
    Foo<char*> foo;
    const char* name = "FooBar";
    foo.Add(name);                 // Causes error
}
```

As mentioned in another another however, this issue just goes away if you use `std::string` instead of C-style strings.

Comment: Is there standard "struct add_const_to_pointee" in std namespace? Would be surprising if there is no.

Answer (score 9):

There is a strong difference between a pointer to a constant object (`T const*`, or `const T*`) and a constant pointer to a non-constant object (`T * const`). In your case the signature of the member `Add` is:

```
void Foo<char *>::Add(char * const& ); // reference to a constant pointer to a 
                                       // non-constant char
```

I usually recommend that people drop the use of `const` on the left hand side exactly for this reason, as beginners usually confuse `typedef`s (or deduced types) with type substitution and when they read:

```
const T& [T == char*]
```

They misinterpret

```
const char*&
```

If the `const` is placed in the *right* place:

```
T const &
```

Things are simpler for beginners, as plain mental substitution works:

```
char * const &
```

---

A different problem than what you are asking, but maybe what you think you want, is:

*Given a type `T` have a function that takes a `U` that is `const T` if `T` is not a pointer type, or `X const *` if `T` is a pointer to `X`*

```
template <typename T>
struct add_const_here_or_there {
    typedef T const type;
};
template <typename T>
struct add_const_here_or_there<T*> {
    typedef T const * type;
};
```

Then you can use this in your signature:

```
template <typename T>
void Foo<T>::Add( const typename add_const_here_or_there<T>::type & arg ) {
     ...
```

Note that I am adding two `const` in the signature, so in your case `char*` will map to `char const * const &`, as it seems that you want to pass a `const&` to something and you also want the pointed type to be `const`.

You might have wondered as of the name for the metafunction: *add_const_here_or_there*, it is like that for a reason: there is no simple way of describing what you are trying to do, which is usually a code smell. But here you have your solution.

Comment: I'm aware of constness that doesn't seem to be my problem here.  If  for example I'm explicit about the type ie: 'void Add( char const * const & Bar )' it works fine and so does 'void Add( const char* const & Bar )'.  However if I put 'const T' back in for 'const char*' or try to typedef it etc then it fails ie it seems using a template argument is failing me here for some reason.

Comment: @user176168: The reason is explained here and in other answers.  Try this: `void Add(char * const & Bar)` -- It doesn't work, right?

Comment: @Benjamin: In my question I state I know that doesn't work I'm trying to find a solution to it.

Comment: @user176168: Right.  But you said in the previous comment: *"using a template argument is failing me here for some reason."* -- Indicating that you didn't know the reason it wasn't working.  So I was pointing out that the reason it wasn't working is explained in this answer.

Comment: @user176168: You are not understanding the answer: *I want the argument to 'Add' to have a `const T` ie `const char*`. To be a `const T` is **not** `const char*`, but `char * const`. `const T` applies to the *whole* type `T` in this case `char*`. What you are asking is to change `T` to `U` where if `T` is a pointer to `X`, `U` is a pointer to `const X`, which can be done but have completely different semantics.

Comment: @user176168: Updated how to technically get the compiler to swallow what you want, although I believe that you are much better off understanding what `const` means in both contexts and rethinking whether what you are asking for really makes any sense. BTW, you might want to consider `std::string` instead of C style strings...

Comment: @David: Great stuff finally got there! That is exactly what I'm asking for. I was going to answer this myself with a similar solution.  If you would be so kind as to separate out your answer I'll tick it as my solution. Thanks

Comment: @user176168: Note that there is a good amount of code smell in that code and the need for that signature. I would recommend that you describe what your real problem is and work a good solution from there.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the template argument to your Foo object to `Foo<const char*>`.  Because if `T=char*`, then `const T=char*const`, not `const char*`.  Trying to coerce it to work is not a good idea and would probably result in undefined behavior.

Comment: In my particular case I can't do that without a lot of code rewriting.  What I really want to know is why this causes undefined behaviour. This logically (to me at least) seems to be perfectly valid and safe ie I'm passing in a pointer to an object that I don't want to modify by a reference to the pointer which I also don't want to modify and I'm not contravening either rule inside that function.

Comment: @user176168: It won't necessarily cause undefined behavior.  I said "probably", though I may have been overstating the risk.  I, personally, never mess around with const cast because it can easily lead to undefined behavior, and I advise others to do the same.  But if you know what you are doing, you can certainly use it without invoking undefined behavior.  Just remember that others with less experience may have to maintain your code.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
Foo<const char*> foo;
const char* name = "FooBar"; 
foo.Add(name);
```

And write `int main()` instead of `void main()`

Answer (score 1):

If passing `const char*` instead of `char*` to `Foo` is not an option you can finesse the correct type with `std::remove_pointer`. This will remove the pointer modifier and allow you to provide a more explicit type.

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct Foo
{
    void Add(typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type const*& Bar ) { printf(Bar); }
};
```

To prevent the pointer value from being modified you can declare the reference as `const` as well.

```
void Add(typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type const* const& Bar )
{ Bar = "name"; } // <- fails
```

If you need to reduce the type from say a *pointer to pointer* you can use `std::decay` along with `std::remove_pointer`

```
void Add(typename std::remove_pointer<typename std::decay<T>::type>::type const*& Bar)
{
    printf(Bar);
}
```

This really depends on what your requirements for `T` are. I suggest assuming only the base type (e.g. `char`) is passed as `T` and building reference and pointer types from that.

Comment: Ok so this partially solves my problem but I don't like it because a) I now have to have multiple functions for the scenario's where T isn't a pointer and b) it isn't really const safe ie I can now do: void Add(typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type const*& Bar ) { Bar = "Boo"; } which changes 'name' to point to "Boo" now eek! Ok so thats easily solved with a const* const & but I still have to have multiple functions.

Comment: `Bar = "Boo"` only changes the pointer value passed, not the contents of the original string. If you want to prevent this change it to `const* const&`. This will prevent you from modifying variable it references. OF course at that point you should probably dump the reference and pass by pointer.